# A Connect Wall to Fly Over

Tags: knowledge, pattern, connect-wall

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #42: Wordless Connecting Walls](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7045/60644)</sup>

---

The 16 images below may be partitioned into 4 groups of 4 connected images.
The overall connection between the groups this time is a little different.
For each group, I want you to choose a **fifth** member - some of the groups have more than five members so you will need to choose carefully.
Each of the **fifth members** will be the name of a character from a movie from the year 2000 and the final answer is the name of the movie.
I will add that the knowledge required here is UK specific - all four groups are related to the UK in some way - but can be found easily on the internet.
[image]

**Can you identify the four groups and the associated fifth group members?**
**What is the movie in which the fifth group members appear as characters?**

Comment: Wow this ones tough!! I am officially tapping out.

Comment: Great puzzle hex (can I call you 'hex'?!) - loved it :)

Comment: @Stiv You can, yes, thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From left to right, top to bottom, these images represent:

> **POSH** (nickname of [Peterborough United FC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterborough_United_F.C.)), [**BUSTER**](https://arthur.fandom.com/wiki/Buster_Baxter) Baxter (from *Arthur*), **SHEARER**, Tree **TOPPER**,
>  Nat King **COLE**, **MEGAMAN**, **SPORTY**, **LAMPARD** (rebus: LAMP + (-c)ARD),
>  **MONEY**, **SCARY**, **EAGLE**, [**G-MAN**](https://half-life.fandom.com/wiki/The_G-Man) (from HalfLife),
>  [**DANDY**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dandy), Mickey **ROONEY**, **BABY**, [***AKIRA***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akira_(1988_film)).

These can then be categorised thus:

> **Group 1: Nicknames of the [Spice Girls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spice_Girls)**
>  POSH, SPORTY, SCARY, BABY
>
>  **Group 2: [Top-scoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_footballers_with_100_or_more_Premier_League_goals) Englishmen in the Premier League (all-time)**
>  Alan SHEARER, Andy COLE, Wayne ROONEY, Frank LAMPARD
>
>  **Group 3: British Comics**
>  [The DANDY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dandy), [BUSTER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buster_(comics)), [EAGLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eagle_(British_comics)), [The TOPPER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Topper_(comics))
>
>  **Group 4: Members of [So Solid Crew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/So_Solid_Crew)**
>  AKIRA, G-MAN, MEGAMAN, MONEY

The additional group members we need to choose are:

> **GINGER** - the fifth Spice Girl (Geri Halliwell)
>  (Robbie) **FOWLER** - the next highest scoring Englishman in PL history
>  [**BUNTY**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/So_Solid_Crew) - a British comic
>  MC **MAC** - another member of So Solid Crew

Finally, a film from the year 2000 which features characters by all of these names is:

> the British stop-motion animated film, **CHICKEN RUN**, in which all of these characters are chickens who spend the duration of the film attempting to *fly over* (note this puzzle's title) the fence of their enclosure!
>
>  [image]

Comment: Absolutely spot on, well done!